# Android: right hamburger icon, left side navigation view?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying do do right side hamburger icon. But navigation view in left side. I searched lot but their logic is

1. Right hamburger icon, right side navigation view
2. Left hamburger icon, left side navigation view

Also I tried to change `tools:openDrawer="start"` of `DrawerLayout`. But it doesn't work what I wanted. So I decided to ask this question.

Comment: You could create a custom toolbar with a hamburger icon on the side you want, and on click, trigger the drawer to open

Comment: In the examples you found with the icon on the right, what problems did you have in getting it to work with the drawer on the left?

Comment: @Kvoid Please add your code to more clear your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are doing this to learn or practise but it is **not advised as per the  material design standards**,

```
to achieve what you want you can do the following
```

Add an image of the hamburger icon in your toolbar and when it is click you can open the drawer from left to right using this flag

> android:layout_gravity="start"

in the drawer